# How to add multi jar path in java

Tags: java, jar

I want to have run java -cp with several jars

How I can do it ?
for example in myProject I have two different jar's :
1.jar a relevant class myClassA 
2.jar b myClassB
The mainclass is myMainClass.java

I tried on windows from cmd:

```
 java -cp c:/myproject/a.jar myClassA,c:/myproject/b.jar myClassB
```

But it didn't work , I tried also ;

```
java -cp c:/myproject/a.jar myClassA;c:/myproject/b.jar myClassB
```

but it didn't work also
Did I miss something ?

Comment: What is the main class of your application ?

Comment: @Berger - myMainClass

Comment: The `-cp` part only lists jars where the classes will be found and it is not the right  place to specify class names , try something like `java -cp c:/myproject/a.jar;c:/myproject/b.jar myMainClass`

Comment: @Berger - does the separation is with ";" ?

Comment: Yes, the path separator on Windows is `;` .

Comment: If you need to execute it in Unix environment, use `:` to separate the jar files instead.

Comment: @Alex - I a using windows

Comment: @user1365697 I just provide more information only, in case someone would like to execute in Unix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create a .class file

```
javac -classpath "[jarname with specified path;jarname1 with specified path]" [java filename]
```

To execute the class file

```
java -cp [jarname with specified path;jarname1 with specified path]: [java filename]
```

Comment: does in my case it should be : java -cp [c:/myproject/a.jar myClassA,c:/myproject/b.jar myClassB] :myMainClass

Comment: did you follow the syntax ?

Comment: yes Did I miss something ?

Comment: did you got any error ?

Comment: Could not find or load main class myClassA

Comment: read this post carefully https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Comment: @user1365697 consider accepting the solution in case i helped in some way.